# Change Access Services Database Name

Tags: service-application, microsoft-access

We are trying out access services for SharePoint and noticed that it generates  its own `db_<guid>` database in the SP database server. We were wondering if it is possible to rename the database or customize the naming convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can customize the naming convention.But it is not straight forward, as renaming a folder.

Below are the steps you need to follow

1. In SharePoint 2010 Management Shell, lets say you want to rename the
   configuration database which is
   content_db_5186280F-C5FE-4495-8096-AFD73A4C524C.  Create a new
   database by using the following command

   `New-SPContentDatabase -Name SharePoint_AdminContent -WebApplication` `"http://sp2010-web1:20376"`
2. Retrieve the Id values assigned to the SharePoint Admin Content database
   By running the following command

   `Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://sp2010-web1:20376 | Get-`SPContentDatabase `| Select Id, Name, WebApplication | Format-List`

3.Move the content from the currently existing database to the newly created database based on the ID that we got in step 2

`Get-SPSite -ContentDatabase 46410944-32c4-4e01-8390-22b693f4fcc2` | `Move-SPSite -DestinationDatabase 86d8e579-fbd8-473e-867d-58b974ee0267`

4. Remove the existing database by running the following command

Remove-SPContentDatabase 46410944-32c4-4e01-8390-22b693f4fcc2

5. Verify that we got rid of the older database run the following command

   `Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://sp2010-web1:20376` | Get-`SPContentDatabase | Select Id, Name, WebApplication | Format-List`

Follow the [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2706/renaming-the-sharepoint-admin-content-database-to-follow-sql-server-naming-conventions/) for more clarity

Comment: And here I thought my post was forgetten. Thank You!